# DirectX/HLSL error PS2.0

Tags: directx, hlsl

i am getting this error

Shader uses texture addressing operations in a dependency chain that is too complex for the target shader model (ps_2_0) to handle.

since i have added this line to my pixelshader:

float Gauss[NUMWT] = { 5.052271056506993e-15, 9.134720359492243e-12, 6.07588281731559e-9, 0.0000014867195067797903, 0.00013383022504883334, 0.004431848388225362, 0.053990966224306644, 0.2419707232244606, 0.39894227826685835, 0.2419707232244606, 0.053990966224306644, 0.004431848388225362, 0.00013383022504883334, 0.0000014867195067797903, 6.07588281731559e-9, 9.134720359492243e-12, 5.052271056506993e-15 };

is this array too big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick test and the array compiles fine for me using ps_2_0 (defining NUMWT as 17) so I guess your error is somewhere else.

Also why should it have any issues handling such "small" arrays? textures are far bigger.

Answer (score 2):

This bit

> Shader uses texture addressing operations

is probably the key to where your problem is. Did the error not come with a line and character number?

Look for spots where you're sampling from textures or calculating the position, within complex paths (possibly branching).